# No configuration has been provided on Kubernetes worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am working on setting up a multi-node, multi hardware server Kubernetes Cluster. I am using Calico and Kubeadm.

I used vagrant with ansible and virtualbox to set node accros the network on many hardware servers.
It is working, the nodes joined the master with the join-command using kubeadm.
And the master is recognizing the remote nodes.

```
vagrant@Server-1-MASTER:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
master              Ready    master   3h37m   v1.18.2
server-1-worker-1   Ready    <none>   3h23m   v1.18.2
server-2-worker-1   Ready    <none>   171m    v1.18.2
server-2-worker-2   Ready    <none>   41m     v1.18.2
```

I am facing a configuration issue that I am trying to fix to set rules and access for the worker nodes.

**Issue:** 
On the workers, an error occurs

```
no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
```

When using kubectl commands

```
vagrant@Server-1-WORKER-1:~$ kubectl get pods

error: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER 

environment variable
```

```
vagrant@Server-1-WORKER-1:~$ kubectl get ns

error: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER 

environment variable
```

And the env variable is empty :

```
vagrant@Server-1-WORKER-1:~$ echo $KUBECONFIG
```

I am asking if someone could help me to fix this problem, set the right variable value to build a complete working cluster.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kubeadm does not automatically setup kubeconfig file on the worker nodes.Copy the kubeconfig file located at `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` from the master nodes over to the worker nodes and set `KUBECONFIG` environment variable to point to the path of the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf from the master node to the worker node to the same location.

Then export the veriable. [image: Find the steps in the image]

export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf