# How do I configure my Kubernetes cluster to work with Gitlab CI?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I'm learning how to use Kubernetes and Gitlab CI/CD so I installed a Gitlab agent into my Kubernetes cluster by following [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/). I wrote a simple hello world pipeline to see if it works

```
image: "docker.io/ubuntu"

stages:
  - build

build-contabo:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "hello world"
```

But the pipeline won't run and complains about missing configuration:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.6.0 (5316d4ac)
  on vmi769777 NWjdRisx
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor 00:09
WARNING: Namespace is empty, therefore assuming 'default'.
Using Kubernetes namespace: default
ERROR: Preparation failed: getting Kubernetes config: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
```

I read on how to [configure an agent](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/repository.html), but could not find anything addressed this error.
I also deployed a [hello world](https://github.com/skynet86/hello-world-k8s) kubernetes deployment to check if my cluster does not work, but it ran successfully.

How can I provide configurations so that my pipeline runs?
And is this a problem with the Kubernetes Cluster or the Gitlab configuration?

Comment: where your `$KUBECONFIG` points to? . This is not gitlab, this is pure kubernetes issue re access to kubeconfig. check [No configuration has been provided on Kubernetes worker nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561364/9929015). Its about workers, however idea the same.  just check

Comment: sorry for the late response. I was not home and the only authorized ssh key was on my desktop.
Anyways, `$KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` which is a file that was there already. I did not change it. I don't think it specifies a namespace anywhere, should it?

Comment: come to think of it, I had this issue the same error message with ssh before I exported kubeconfig. It did not fix it for the gitlab pipeline though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

So `kubectl` works because when running it I am in the root user.
This user has a kubernetes config in its home `/home/root/.kube`.

The gitlab runner runs in a different user, in my case `gitlab-runner`.
This user doesn't have a kubernetes config dir.

Copying it from root solves the issue: `cp -r /home/root/.kube /home/gitlab-runner/.kube`

Comment: Beside `cache` personally I don't have anything else inside `.kube`. A simple `mkdir .kube` inside `gitlab-runner` user's `home` directory should suffice. I did try that and it doesn't work. GitLab's CICD mentions `KUBERNETES_MASTER`  and that the environment variable should be set. However where exactly is apparently not important information according to the GitLab developers. :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting KUBE_CONFIG_PATH? I was getting the same error, but export KUBE_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/kubeconfig seems to fix the issue.

Comment: I have a `KUBECONFIG` set is there a difference between the two?